# What's the syntax for variables in an MSSQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I have a simple query like this:

```
select * from mytable where id > 8
```

I want to make the 8 a variable.  There's some syntax like

```
declare @myvar int
myvar = 8
```

but I don't know the exact syntax.

What is it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm starting to wonder about your name, Mr. Database

Comment: My middle name is "what's a" :-]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's:

```
DECLARE @MyVariable INT
SET @MyVariable = 8
```

Answer (score 5):

```
declare @myvar int

Set @myvar = 8

select * from mytable where id > @myvar
```

Answer (score 3):

To clarify: both SET and SELECT work, but SET is the ANSI standard.  However, if you're setting multiple values at once, then

```
SET @one = 1
SET @two = 2
```

will be very slightly slower than

```
SELECT @one = 1, @two = 2
```

What you gain in speed may well be offset by readability and clarity, however.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @myvar int

select @myvar = 8
```